# Simple Python 3.4.3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner (only coding for 14 weeks) and I'm so confused as to what's happening here. All I want to do is ask a simple question and print back another print statement, but no matter what, it always answers "you said yes!". Someone please help me.

```
input("This Python program will ask you a series of questions. Are you Ready? ")

if input == "Yes" or "y":
    print("You said yes!")

elif input == "No" or "n":
    print("You said no!")

else:
    print("You said neither.")
```

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple issues in your code.

- First, the string you get from the `input` method isn't store anywhere. Try printing the `input`"variable", and you will get :

  ```
  <built-in function input>
  ```

  Instead, store the output of the `input` method in a variable and use this variable instead of `input`.
- Second issues, your tests. When you write  `if input == "Yes" or "y":`, I guess you want to test if the string is equal to "Yes" or to "y". But in reality, the test happening can be written :

  ```
  if (input == "Yes") or ("y"):
  ```

  Your test is then composed of two parts : the first test is correct, but the second one is just `test if "y"`, which is always true since the string "y" is not null.

  You should replace it by :

  ```
  if input == "Yes" or input == "y":
  ```

  Or even simpler :

  ```
  if input in ("Yes", "y"):
  ```

---

To conclude, the final code is simply :

```
str = input("This Python program will ask you a series of questions. Are you Ready? ")

if str in ("Yes","y"):
    print("You said yes!")

elif str in ("No","n"):
    print("You said no!")

else:
    print("You said neither.")
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to work more on understanding what input, str in, and else does.

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to store the input in a variable:

```
 string = input(...
```

Then, you have to repeat `input == "y"` for the second of `or` conditions:

```
if string == "Yes" or string == "y":
```

or

```
if string in ("Yes", "y"):
```

Comment: To elaborate, the string "y" has a truth value of True, which is why the if statement will always evaluate to true. The same holds for the "n" value which must also be compared with input.